# Can I use combustion gases for heating?

Tags: temperature, applied-physics, combustion

What is the temperature of the carbon dioxide gas released from combustion of wood?

If I let the gases escape directly, then only some heat is transferred by the gas to the heating drum and the rest of the heat escapes into atmosphere. If I trap the gases for some time, they will release more heat before escaping into atmosphere.

I can pass the gases through heat exchanger. if it is a standalone system, I can trap the gases in a pressure cooker type system (some gases will exit from below). If you have some other way, can do that as well.

Knowing the temperature helps me make appropriate decisions.

Comment: Is what you are asking different from a furnace with a heat exchanger?

Comment: You're overthinking it. What you're describing is every direct-fire or open heating system which includes every combustion heater where you don't bother to install a heat exchanger. The gaseous combustion products mix with the air and all of that is used for heating.

Comment: @DKNguyen That sounds dangerous, I didn't even know those existed.

Comment: @noah Not really if the setting is correct. Not all heaters are HVAC systems and direct fired ones that are, are used more in industrial settings. Not that different from a fancy bon fire.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ah yeah industrial settings make more sense. I was thinking about CO and CO2 poisoning in housing arrangements.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. the device that does this is called a *wood-burning stove*.

Comment: Don't regular wood-burning stoves usually have some type of exhaust pipe?

Comment: @ noah, certainly- but it acts as a heat exchanger, transferring its heat from the flue gases to the air in the room. This prevents you from being poisoned by the smoke!

Comment: Ah I interpreted the original question before the edits as *directly* using the CO2 from combustion for heating, hence my confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Found this on the net. The typical furnace outlet temperature of flue gases is usually around 1200 °C which will decreases gradually along the pathway of heat transfer, while the temperature of the flue gases going to stack is around 150 °C.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).